# How can I write math symbols or Greek letters in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, unicode

How can I write math symbols or Greek letters in Gmail?

Answer (score 5):

The most popular answer on gmail forums seems to be type it out in word and copy and paste into gmail.
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=7314e7bc4a4dc7cc&hl=en

Comment: nice idea +1 ....

Answer (score 4):

**There is no one unique way to do this...** but I can share what I do, personally.

- Use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) on any site. [Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) for example. Now go to any question, and type a Greek letter using MathJax. For example, `$\alpha$`. In the preview, you see the rendered version of alpha. You can copy it and paste. Here's the alpha I copied: `α`.  **Note: don't post that answer. Just quit the window.**
- ***NIX USERS:** if you have a good memory power, then memorize the unicodes of all the Greek letter. Now press Ctrl + Shift + u which brings you an underlined "u". Type the unicode and then press space. Tada! For example, I typed this using unicode: `β`.
- **WINDOWS USERS:** there's an alt code for everything (almost). Just press `alt + the given alt code`. Find the list of alt codes [here](http://www.alt-codes.net/).
- **MAC USERS:** find the guide [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3871).

Most ways of inputting these characters can be found on [Wikipedia Unicode Input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hexadecimal_code_input) page.

Answer (score 2):

You can google for the symbol and copy/ paste.  I do this all the time with the degree symbol...quick and easy, don't have to open up a Word .doc...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Windows, there is the Character Map utility which should give you virtually any symbol or letter in any alphabet you want.

I don't know what they are, but I expect Mac and Linux have similar utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Save time, here is a quick search list for Greek and mathematical symbols for MS Word. Copy and paste the symbols to your document. Open the Word document here:

http://www.avdweb.nl/miscellaneous/ms-word-symbols-list.html

Answer (score 0):

[GmailTeX](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html) does exactly what you want.

Comment: Sure, more info would be useful, and the actual link address.  That being said, it's the best solution, and it was sitting with a negative overall value.  Let's not throw the baby out with the bath water!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Alt Codes or just this [keyboard to write math symbols and greek letters](http://www.mathkeyboard.com/)

Comment: How does this answer the question?